# Is This An Anti-Pattern - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have just started using React and working on a small app, in the meantime I made a small show and hide modal. I wanted to know the way I have made it is a wrong way to do it. If this is an anti-pattern how should I go about it?

```
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {show: false};
      this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
              <h2 className={styles.main__title}>Helloooo!</h2>
              <Modal ref='show'/> 
              <button onClick={this.showModal} className={styles.addtask}>&#x2795;</button>
           </div>
       );
   }

   showModal(){
       this.setState({
          show: true
       });
       this.refs.show.showModal();
   }

}
```

The modal component which i have made is using this logic, it hooks the dom elements and modifies using the `document.queryselector`. Is this a right way to do the dom manipulation in react.

The modal code which i have used is this :

```
class Modal extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this);
    this.showModal = this.showModal.bind(this);
    this.state = { modalHook: '.'+styles.container };
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <div onClick={this.hideModal} className={styles.container}>
                <div className={styles.container__content}>
                    <div className={styles.card}>
                        <div className={styles.card__header}>
                            <h2>Add new task</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.card__main}>
                            <Input type="text" placeholder="enter the task title" />
                            <Input type="textarea" placeholder="enter the task details" />
                        </div>
                        <div className={styles.card__actions}>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

showModal(){
    let container = document.querySelector(this.state.modalHook);
    container.classList.add(styles.show);    
}
hideModal(e){
    let container = document.querySelector(this.state.modalHook);
    if(e.target.classList.contains(styles.container)){
        container.classList.remove(styles.show);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your code, not some pretty pictures.

Comment: you added this same App component twice.

Comment: You don't need to get props since you're not using them. Everything else seems workable. What do you think is wrong?

Comment: Did you create the Modal Component? If that's the case, I think that you should avoid using refs. I would use a prop `show` and assign to it the value of `this.state.show`. With your current implementation you should remove the state since you are not using it at all.

Comment: you can hide and show your modal by computing css classes based on passed flag to the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example looks good and simple, but accordingly to [this](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs) it is better don't overuse `refs`.

And also it might be helpful to lifting state up, like described [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html).

Here my example:

```
class Modal extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: props.show};
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
        let modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        if (prevProps.show) {
            modal.classList.remove('hidden');
        } else {
            modal.className += ' hidden';
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div id="modal" className={this.state.show ? '' : 'hidden'}>
                My modal content.
            </div>
        );
    }
}
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {show: false};
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }
    handleClick() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            show: !prevState.show
        }));
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    Launch modal
                </button>
                <Modal show={this.state.show} />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Here i don't pretend for ultimate truth, but try to provide another option how you can reach desired result.

Comment: why jquery included? Can't you just build css classes based on flag and hide and show model based on that? - in my opinion - there is no need for another big library like jquery when you have React - I would consider it as antipattern to manipulate HTML with other way than react even.

Comment: @Kejt Thank you! You are absolutely right! I'am agree with you that jquery is redundant, but I decided use it just for simplicity (because everyone familiar with jquery) and tried to provide only vision how it can be done. I've updated my example, now it is much more easier.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you require you don't need to use refs at all. You can pass the state down the to child component as a prop. When the state updates the prop will automatically update. You can then use this prop to switch a class. You can see it in action on [jsbin here](https://jsbin.com/xezemovaja/edit?html,js,console,output)

```
const Modal = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className={props.show ? 'show' : 'hide'}>modal</div>
  )
}

const styles = {
    main__title: 'main__title',
    addtask: 'addtask'
}

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {show: false};
      this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
   }

   render() {
       return (
           <div>
              <h2 className={styles.main__title}>Helloooo!</h2>
              <Modal show={this.state.show} /> 
              <button onClick={this.toggleModal} className={styles.addtask}>&#x2795;</button>
           </div>
       );
   }

   toggleModal(){
       this.setState({
          show: !this.state.show
       });
   }

}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```